# How to prevent Ionic 3 app close by hardware back button in android?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, back-button

How to prevent Ionic 3 app close by hardware back button in android?
I don't want to close the app if the user hit the back button. App is a single page application on I don't have page to pop. I want to put alert to ask user want to exit app or not on pressing back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Hardware Back Button API:

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

...

constructor(private platform: Platform) {
  this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10, () => {
    console.log('Handler was called!');
  });
}
```

[Hardware API Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/hardware-back-button)